# Send Failure Email and Fail Package or Job

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several SSIS packages that I inherited that have been scheduled as Jobs in SSMS that send email notifications **inside** of the SSIS package. So, if a particular piece of one of the SSIS packages fail, certain users receive an email notification with the failure and the details of the failure. This works fine for individual packages or SSMS jobs that do not depend on the failure or success of a package ahead of it.

My problem and my question centers around how do I allow the failure email notifications to complete in the package but fail the package in such a way that the step in the SSMS job fails so that other steps do not kick off? Is there a way to do this without having to undo all of the failure notifications inside of the SSIS packages and moving those failure notifications out somewhere else?

I'm using SQL Server 2008-R2.

EDIT: If I simply have the task fail the package, the Failure Send Mail task will not kick off.

[image]

Instead, I want it to do this,

[image]

but capture that the package was actually a failure. Can I do this with the package as it is, or will I have to have the package fail and redo all of the packages so the failure notifications are sent a different way. Again, this is important for SSMS jobs that contain multiple steps, not so much for the individual packages themselves.

Comment: Did you set FailPackageOnFailure to true, and same for FailParent?   See here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399999/ssis-fail-package-on-failure?rq=1

Comment: But it isn't failing really. If I have it fail the package, then it is killed right there and will not fire off the Send Mail Task that is linked to the Failure constraint. I need the individual task to fail and then move along to the Send Mail task for the failure. But once the Send Mail task completes, the package finishes as a success instead of a failure.

Comment: Edited question to hopefully include an answer to your questions.

Comment: Follow the "Notify of package failure" task with a script task that does nothing but return a failed status.   Set FailPackageOnFailure to true on the script task.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: That is what I was leaning to, but I just wasn't sure if I wanted an extra task that is only there to fail, but weighing that against redoing all of the failure notifications does seem like a good option. Thank you for at least confirming that I was on the right track.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, please do not simply edit titles just for the sake of it. I read the link and there was definitely no consensus, and it seems at least split on whether it is okay or not but seemed to me that more people think it's fine (for related questions and other reasons). And the overwhelming majority of people at least said that people who just go through and edit questions for the sake of it without offering any assistance to the question are more of a bother.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, especially the bottom. I would link to that article now, but there's no anchor for the final section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno whether SSIS from SQL Server **2008** had this property already or was it released later, but you can do *this* on the mail task to indicate this it's just for error handling. Also, you can set `FailPackageOnFailure` afterwards:

[image: Setting ForceExecutionResult on executable]

Comment: Thank you for this. I have seen this property but wasn't sure if that would fail the actual job, but it does seem to work. I really was hoping to not have to add another task at the end of these packages just for the sake of failure. So, thank you for saving me this extra task.